# Медвежонок панда. Нужен дефис?

Tags: приложение

Медвежонок-панда или медвежонок панда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще встречается вариант  ***медвежонок панда*** по образцу вид + род (сравнить: птица ворон, дерево сосна). Этот вариант используется в названии игрушек, в сказках и рассказах о природе.

Но дефисное написание ***медвежонок-панда*** в принципе тоже возможно, если  считать, что панда – это приложение в постпозиции.

Примеры:

― Орли показала Глебу майку, где был нарисован **медвежонок панда**, качающийся на качелях. [Алексей Иванов. Комьюнити (2012)]

В маленьком холле ...восседал **игрушечный медвежонок-панда** и важно кивал головой, посвечивая рубиновыми глазками. [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Жук в муравейнике (1979)]